# How to connect to Apache Ignite cluster from laptop for dev?

Tags: ssh, ignite

Is it possible to connect to an Apache Ignite cluster from outside of the network (e.g. from dev laptop) using ssh tunnels? Only in clientMode. If it is possible how?

I have seen various half posts about this but nothing that puts it all together. Tx.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to use a [thin client](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/getting-started-with-thin-clients) that requires to open just a single port on the server nodes end. Check the `org.apache.ignite.configuration.ClientConnectorConfiguration.port` setting, by default the servers listen for the [thin client connections on port 10800](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/getting-started-with-thin-clients#configuring-thin-client-connector).

[Thick clients](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/getting-started/concepts#thick-vs-thin-clients) require to [open discovery and communication SPI](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/clustering/network-configuration) ports on the cluster side that might require more heavy-lifting for you. [This page](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/clustering/connect-client-nodes) summarizes thick client-related settings if you go this route.

Comment: Tx. I switched to the thin client and now its easy: ssh -N -L 10800:localhost:10800 user@ignitehost.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your network configuration. Try to make it so that your laptop can ping your cluster and your cluster can ping your laptop.

Then adjust the ipfinder (in Ignite config) on the laptop and on the cluster accordingly.

Comment: Tx. I am busy trying to get a VPN working to do that. I was hoping to avoid that step.

Comment: You can try do it through shh tunnel.

Comment: Yes but what tunnels do I need to setup? And how to I configure the clientMode Ignite in my app?